# how to set an X-Forwarded-For in http request in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, http-headers, ip, pyqt

I would like to know how can I add `X-Forwarded-For` paramet to my header.

for example if I want to change user-uagent in my application, I would do some thing like this:

```
class MyBrowser(QWebPage):
    ''' Settings for the browser.'''

    def __init__(self):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)

    def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        ''' Returns a User Agent that will be seen by the website. '''
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1295.0 Safari/537.15"
```

and than I would do something like:

```
class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, user_info):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.setPage(MyBrowser())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QWebView has `void QWebView::load ( const QNetworkRequest & request, QNetworkAccessManager::Operation operation = QNetworkAccessManager::GetOperation, const QByteArray & body = QByteArray() )`. You can set any header on QNetworkRequest with `void QNetworkRequest::setRawHeader ( const QByteArray & headerName, const QByteArray & headerValue )`

I'm not python developer but in C++ it would be something like this:

```
QWebView * view = new QWebView;
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://www.google.pl"));
req.setRawHeader("X-Forwarded-For", "MyData");
req.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1295.0 Safari/537.15");
view->load(req); // will perform get operation by default
view->show();
```